# What is 日本橋{にっぽんばし}？

Tags: usage, culture

So I'm doing some exercises in Minna no Nihongo and run across these two sentences:

- どこで安い電気製品を売っていますか。
- 大阪の`日本橋`で売っています。

I looked it up and saw it mean `japanese bridge` but the way it is in the sentence it sounds like the name of a store or something like that. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In the quoted dialog, the answer does not match the question.  Does the book really say “ところで” at the beginning of the first sentence?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto どうもすみません。(is this the proper way to say "oops sorry and thank you"?)

Comment: No problem.  どうもすみません is literally “sorry” and I do not consider it as an expression of thanks, although some people may consider that どうもすみません also implies thanks.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Oh. Well どうもありがとうございます。 too ：）

Comment: どういたしまして (you are welcome). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the name of a place in Ōsaka. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nipponbashi . Also note that there is a Nihonbashi (日本橋) in Tōkyō.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Dono 's answer, it is important in this context that 日本橋 is one of the famous electric districts. Japan has several electric districts, where you can buy electronic parts and products. The largest is 秋葉原 in Tokyo, the next is 日本橋 in Osaka, the next is 大須 in Nagoya. There is also エジソンプラザ in 石川町, Yokohama.